# Changing JavaScript source

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code is not changing the javascript source:

```
if($.browser.msie){
    var new_scr=document.createElement('script');
    new_scr.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_scr); 
}
```

I have a feeling it might be because it is missing the `type="text/javascript">`

I know it is not working because I have a function that works only with jquery 1.3 and the function is not working.

You can find the full code here: cloudintegrationservice.com

Comment: No, the "type" should not be necessary.

Comment: Anyway what exactly is the problem?  What makes you think that it's not working?

Comment: Are you viewing it with Firefox? ;D

Comment: Note that javascript operations will only change the browser's internal representation of the document, it won't change the data you see when you `<right click> => View source`

Comment: Have you included JQuery or any other library by default. If not, what is the value of $

Comment: Your function is "not working" because it is probably called *before* your new jQuery script is loaded. Anyway you did not show the actual related code that's "not working" so it's really hard to tell the problem.

Comment: did you make sure to call that function after this script has been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.getScript()` to load the script file instead: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/